# How to revert misconfigured BOOT_ORDER value on RPI4?

Tags: boot, pi-4, sd-card, recovery, pi4-eeprom

I've had my RPI4 configured to boot from the network if there is no SD card inserted (for bare metal programming) but firmware update restored it back to SD boot only. So I've tried to make it boot from the network again using this procedure: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bcm2711_bootloader_config.md. But I've misconfigured `BOOT_ORDER` setting it to 0x2 instead of 0x12. Now it does not boot from SD card at all. It boots from network fine. I have `BOOT_UART` option enabled and I see that it doesn't even try to boot from SD card. It tries to boot few times over network and stops, giving `FATAL @ 0x80001fc2` message. The official documentation says:

> The Raspberry Pi 4 has an SPI-attached EEPROM (4MBits/512KB), which contains code to boot up the system and replaces bootcode.bin previously found in the boot partition of the SD card. Note that if a bootcode.bin is present in the boot partition of the SD card in a Pi 4, it is ignored.

but it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there a way to restore original EEPROM contents? I would like to avoid desoldering and reprogramming the EEPROM chip since it would void the warranty for sure.

Comment: You should be able to reprogram the EEPROM https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/booteeprom.md

Comment: That would be the case if I was able to run Linux.

Comment: You don't need Linux - everything is in recovery.bin which is bootable.

Comment: I got it working. Seems I got confused by recover* files in NOOBS archive. These don't seem to work. I didn't know that there is separate archive with EEPROM recovery stuff on Raspberry Pi download page.

Comment: Forget NOOBS, it just makes things horribly complex when your RPi won't boot. It also wastes 1.3GB of space on your SDCard. If you're only using NOOBS to boot Raspbian then just flash the card with plain Raspbian using Balena's Etcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download bootloader archive from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/. Unpack it on to  freshly FAT32 formatted µSD card (mine was partitioned and had `boot` flag enabled for the partition). RPI4 should be able to boot from it and restore EEPROM contents. If it succeeds it will start to flash ACT LED rapidly. There is also some progress info outputted to its serial port during this process. `recover*` files from NOOBS archive will NOT work.

Comment: The boot flag isn't used. The RPi only boots from the first primary FAT partition.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the [Raspberry Pi Imager](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/) on your Mac, Linux computer or Windows PC.

Use it to install a bootloader* onto an SD card.

Boot the Raspberry Pi using the SD card. The bootloader will be updated.

* In the Imager, select Misc utility images, then Bootloader, then choose one of the boot options corresponding to the boot order you prefer. Choose a storage location. Then choose Write.

The same imager can be used to install various operating systems.